# HTML/CSS: 4 pixels of space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make [a little website](http://www.steffelmusic.nl/cs) but I have a little css problem. If you hover over the names at the bottom of the photo, the photo comes up like it should. But there's a space of 4 pixels underneath, which I can't seem to remove. I've tried `margin-bottom: -4px` but that made the animation weird.

I guess it's a simple thing, but I just can't put my finger on the solution. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `vertical-align:bottom;`

Images are, by default, `inline-block` elements. This basically means that they are treated like characters, but can have width and height.

The thing to note about characters is that they have a *baseline*. Most letters are aligned with this baseline, but some (such as q, p, j, g) drop below it.

Therefore, since images are aligned to the baseline, a little extra space is left underneath. `vertical-align:bottom` overrides, this, forcing the image to align to the bottom of the text. Note that these alignments apply even if there is no text.

Comment: Awesome. Didn't think on giving the `<img>` some style code. Thanks a lot :-) thanks for the explanation, too. I was not aware of that.

Comment: No problem. This seems to be a very common issue that not even the author of Quirks Mode [could figure out](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html). Yet it's so simple once you know it...

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your css:

```
.banner .photo img {
    display:block;
    padding:0px;
}
```